# using 'replacing' keyword doesn't change the value in this COBOL code

Tags: cobol

I'm pretty new in COBOL programming, and I can't understand why my code doesn't generate what I want; which is changing the value of 'm-poem'.

```
   data division.
   working-storage section.

   01 m-poem pic A(50) value 'nothing here'.
```

and using this:

```
  procedure division.

  initialize m-poem replacing alphanumeric data by
  -    "This is the way
  -         "I chose to take".
  display m-poem.
```

what I get instead is : "nothing here". which is the original value of 'poem' not the replaced one.

Comment: [This page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ref/rpbeg10.htm) shows several examples of `replacing alphanumeric data by`.  None of them involve the sort of text literal you're using in your sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*(Thank you for my introduction to COBOL.)*</sup>

The reason this isn't working is because you are attempting to replace `alphanumeric data` of a record that only has `alphabetic` data within it.

You can resolve this by doing either of the following:

1. `A(50)` must be paired with `replacing alphabetic data`; *or*
2. `replacing alphanumeric data` must be paired with `X(50)`.